# Unifier api to list all folders always gives 500

Tags: rest, primavera

-- I had been trying to use this Unifier API get list of folders. /ws/rest/dm/node/properties

Always get the following response

```json
{
  "data":
  [
  ],
  "message":
  [
  ],
  "status":500
}
```

Not sure what needs to be done to get it correct. I do not have any access their support page as well.

Primaver unifier API.

Expecting to list all folders from unifier
and also download those folders/files using Unifier API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!